# Can we change parameters value at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

Suppose, we have a var type and we want to hard code some values just for testing purpose something in this:

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sof);
```

Here, i want to change some properties values in payload variable at runtime.On Hover,i can see all properties with values.I want to know can i change one or two of them 
and post those changed values alongwith original values to this:

await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

Please someone tell me how to do it.

Comment: I think you can use watch window and change the value at run time...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just re assign the payload in Immediate window?

Comment: In VS Debug -> Windows -> Immediate.  Then put a break point where you want to change the info. When you hit that breakpoint just run your code in Immediate like:  payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sof);